# Pings do not work with manually set up Flow Rules

Tags: sdn, openflow, onos

I am currently playing around with ONOS and OpenFlow. I am using ONOS 2.0.0 and mininet-wifi. I have to following scenario: A wireless node moves between multiple access points. I would like to set up flow rules for the current and the following access point. The topology looks like this:

[image: Topology]

The host with IP 10.0.0.1 moves between the access points. However, I cannot get pings to work between the two hosts. At the access points I have two rules forwarding everything from their port 1 to 2 to and vice versa:
[image: AP]

In the core switch my manual flow rules look e.g. like that:
[image: Core Switch]

What am I doing wrong here? What is the reason I cannot ping in this scenario? The rules of the reactive forwarding app do not look really different. One difference in the code is that I am using FlowRule objects while the reactive forwarding uses the ForwardingObjective object. I also tried that without any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the ARP requests were not answered. I had to start the ProxyARP application of ONOS. By that ONOS responds to received ARP requests properly. After that the flow rules were used as expected for sending the ping packages.